# Unable to telnet SMTP server from ec2 prod machine

Tags: amazon-ec2, telnet

I'm unable to telnet my SMTP server via ec2. What can be the possible reasons for the same. The SMTP server is running fine, tested it from the local machine.

```
telnet smtp.example.com 587
```

This is the command used? Can there be some firewalls restricting the same? How to check them?

Updated:-

1. I checked my firewalls. It's inactive.
2. Have also checked securoty groups, all outbound traffic is allowed.
3. Tried restarting the server too, still unable to telnet.
4. Launched a new ec2 machine and it worked like a charm. What am I missing here?

Comment: Check the security group attached to the EC2 instance.

Comment: Already checked. All outbound traffic is allowed.